# Why is new String("Hello") invalid in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, constructor

What is the logic/reason behind making

```
String s= new String("Hello World");
```

Illegal in C#?
The error is

> The best overloaded method match for `string.String(char*)' has some invalid arguments

I'm not interested in the API docs, I am interested in why this is illegal.

Is is because of pooling static strings? like Java pools Integer(-128) to Integer(127) with horrendous results? ( of course strings too )

Comment: Because the string class contains no constructor taking a single string argument?

Comment: (Java does have a `new String(String)` constructor -- this is most notably useful for academic playing with "new string objects" and "interned string objects" as Java Strings do not overload `==` ... anyway, since Java *has* it, why not C#? I hope that some of the answers might try to address this, if it is addressable for any sane reason [other than it wasn't deemed useful/necessary].)

Comment: Features have to be justified on a cost-benefit basis. What's the benefit that justifies the cost? If there's no benefit that justifies the cost then it should be illegal simply on the economic grounds that we have better things to do than to design, specify, implement, test, document and maintain a constructor that no one uses or needs.

Comment: @Eric L, care to make it an answer?

Comment: Also I find new String("Hello"); both obvious and elegant but maybe thats just me =/

Comment: +1 on the OP; if there had been a constructor in the implementation of String class which could take a string, this wouldn't have happened. I have posted an answer below.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Please do differ! What is the compelling customer benefit of "making a new ref" to a string? There have been days when what I dearly need is "make a cloned copy of the state of this IEnumerator", but I have never once said to myself "I need to have two strings that are identical in every way but their managed address, thereby guaranteed to take up twice as much space as necessary in memory". I'm not seeing the benefit here.

Comment: @pst: How is "because Java has it" in *any* way a justification for a feature in C#? Features in C# are justified by their compelling benefits to our customers. (And I note that the most obvious feature of C# that is there "because Java has it" -- array covariance -- is deeply broken and causes serious performance and correctness problems.) I presume the Java designers had some reason to add this feature; ask them if you want their explanation. I'm not a Java expert, so I have no idea why Java has such a feature.

Comment: @EricLippert, I just said to myself "I need to have two strings that are identical in every way but their managed address, thereby guaranteeing that there are two copies of that sequence of characters in memory." I said this because I am implementing a fixed-capacity StringBuilder class that does not dynamically allocate memory and I want its (rarely used) ToString method to return a copy of the current string. Following which I will use unsafe code to modify the string being copied. (Granted, I know how to allocate and copy myself, so I can solve my own perhaps-unusual use case.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be rather pointless to use the constructor to create a new string based on another existing string - that's why there is no constructor overload that allows this. Just do

```
string s = "Hello World";
```

Comment: So why is there such a construct in Java? ;-)

Comment: I thought copy constructors were useful.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe What is the point of copying an object that can never be mutated? :)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Since strings are immutable you can just use the original - no point in making a copy

Comment: I can see a few possible uses for such a thing.  Among other things, although String is *supposed* to be immutable, that doesn't guarantee that strings won't get changed.  If one confirms that a pre-existing string is valid and does some processing with it, there will be a danger that the string might get modified between the test and the processing.  Making a copy of the string first will eliminate that danger.

Comment: @supercat: you mean a string *variable* not a string. The variable of course can point to a different string - still the string itself is immutable

Comment: @supercat How can a string (*object*) be mutated?

Comment: @Captain Giraffe `==` (as all operators) is non-polymorphic. `object.==(object)` is an object-identity. However, `string.==(string)` is value-equality. This is in sharp contrast to Java (which has no `==` overloading).

Comment: Very good point pst. Still I feel very unsatisfied as to my original question.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: There are a variety of ways, e.g. using Reflection or COM interop, by which one can get a writable pointer to the characters within a string.  Given such a pointer, one could write to the data within a string.  Generally, if one needed to e.g. have some unmanaged code write to a string, the proper way to do that would be to pass a StringBuilder rather than a string (interop code includes special magic to facilitate that), so there's probably no reason code *should* mutate strings except in testing to ensure that other code will be robust even if strings get mutated.

Comment: I guess there is no hard technical reason why it *shouldn't* be allowed - as @JonB and others point out though it might give the impression that you are creating a copy when in fact that's not what's happening.

Comment: The semantics of `String s= new String("Hello World");
` is by no measure unclear. It was a conscious choice.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: as a way of better understanding (for me) the reasoning behind your question, I'd like to ask whether you would also expect this to work: DateTime dt2=new DateTime(dt1), where dt1 is some other DateTime.

Comment: @CoreyKosak Yes very much so, not only on the obvious dt1.Now but as a generic yes.

Comment: OK, that's helpful. And as a second question that helps me elicit your assumptions, if I were to say s2=new string(s1), where s1 is some other string, would you expect the output of Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2) to be true or false?

Comment: @CoreyKosak: I would expect that `var X = new anyClass(anyParams);` should set X to a new object which is distinct from any other.  The fact that the `String(Char[])` constructor deviates from that pattern does suggest ambiguity about what a `String(String)` constructor should do, though I would posit that unless other types also deviate from that pattern the proper resolution for resolving the ambiguity would be to have `String(Char[])` follow the example set by other types.

Comment: unsafe code is part of C#, and makes it easy to mutate a string. Granted, it's not common practice, but it is a perfectly valid thing to do, for example when minimizing dynamic allocation of strings in a real-time or embedded environment. See the answer I just added for more discussion.

Answer (score 8):

Because strings are immutable and have language support in how they are constructed.

In your example, since you are using a string literal, it will get interned. Any copied string that would have been created from it would end up being the same exact reference, as it would come from the intern pool.

Comment: Why does the immutability of strings come into play at all?

Comment: You are constructing a string from a string - both are identical and can't be changed. What's the point? Just use the original string.

Comment: The pooling argument is the only sound argument I've found so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It's .NET, not C#.  Look at the constructors for [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) - none accept a System.String

So it's "illegal" for the same reason you can't construct a string with an int.

```
string x = new String(1);
```

---

[Raymond Chen](http://blog.ryjones.org/2005/07/12/product-development/)

The answer to "Why doesn't this feature exist?" is usually "By default features don't exist.  Somebody has to implement them."

---

My guess is that every time someone sat down to implement this constructor.  They thought about String.ToString's implementation and determined the constructor would logically undermine that method.

Comment: My point is that no one made it illegal. They just didn't specify the constructor you expect to be there. The "Why" question you should be asking is "Why do you expect it to be there?". If it's because you come from the Java world, then Welcome to .Net - things are different here.

Comment: No If anything I'm from the c++ world. But I appreciate the welcome =)

Comment: +1 No offense to the rest, but I believe, this post deserves more upvotes than the rest

Answer (score 2):

It would give the impression that the string is being cloned, but strings are immutable.

Comment: These are not necessarily orthogonal, but strongly related.

Answer (score 2):

A string is immutable **until you start messing with unsafe code**, so the language designers chose not to add a feature that isn't needed **in normal usage**. That is not to say it wouldn't be handy in certain situations.

If you do this:

```
string a = "foobar";
string b = a;
Mutate(a, "raboof");
Console.WriteLine("b={0}", b);
```

where:

```
unsafe void Mutate(string s, string newContents)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(newContents.Length == s.Length);
    fixed (char* ps = s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < newContents.Length; ++i)
        {
            ps[i] = newContents[i];
        }
    }
}
```

You may be surprised to know that *even though string 'a' is the one that was mutated* the output will be:

```
b=raboof
```

In this situation one would like to write:

```
string a = "foobar";
string b = new String(a);
Mutate(a, "raboof");
Console.WriteLine("b={0}", b);
```

And expect to see output like:

```
b=foobar
```

But you can't, because it is not part of the implementation of System.String.

And I guess a reasonable justification for that design decision is that anyone comfortable writing something like the unsafe Mutate method is also capable of implementing a method to clone a string.

Comment: Even when one isn't using unsafe code, there are some situations in which it may be helpful to have a string which is known not to be reference-equal to any other string that could possibly exist anywhere in the universe--to validate the behavior of string interning code if nothing else.  That having been said, the fact that repeated calls to `new String(' ', 0)` yield the same instance means that it's unclear that repeated calls to `new String("Fred")` wouldn't do likewise.

Comment: True enough about the hypothetical behaviour a String(string) constructor would have. All the more reason to write your own unsafe Clone method. :)

Comment: Personally, I think that .NET should have either had class-type constructors always yield new object instances, or else had them invoke factory methods which would have the option to return cached instances.  I can appreciate that in most cases sharing zero-length-string instances would be a good thing, but the proper way to handle that would have been to have a `String.Repeat(char,int)` overload whose spec indicated that it was free to intern string instances for whatever parameter parameter combinations seemed worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you are trying to use takes in...

> A pointer to a null terminated array of Unicode characters

...rather than a String.

(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331864(v=VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make Eric Lipperts comment visible:

**Features have to be justified on a cost-benefit basis. What's the benefit that justifies the cost? If there's no benefit that justifies the cost then it should be illegal simply on the economic grounds that we have better things to do than to design, specify, implement, test, document and maintain a constructor that no one uses or needs.**

Answer (score 0):

At my end, I get this:

> The best overloaded method match for `string.String(char[])' has some invalid arguments

May be you typed "char *" in place of "char[]" while posting.

Perhaps this has got to do with our historic understanding of literals. Prior to C#, a value enclosed in quotes (like "astringvalue") could be treated as a character pointer. However in C# "astringvalue" is just an object of type string class. The statement:

```
String s= new String("Hello World");
```

would imply create an object of type String class and invoke its constructor. The compiler checks the list of [constructors available for string class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s83eyw9.aspx). It cannot find any constructor that could accept a string object ("Hello world"). Like in any other situation, the compiler makes a best guess of which is the "closest" method from the list of overloaded methods - in this case, assumes a string value "Hello world" to be closest to a character array (char []) - and tells you that your "Hello world" (value that you passed) is an invalid value for "char []".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, The basic difference is the 'Pass by Reference' and 'Pass by Value' in .NET and JAVA.

Leading to a [design pattern](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Class/Aconstructorforcopyinganobjectofthesame.htm) in Java, for a reason which may be

> A constructor for copying an object of the same class.

In .NET you don't require such constructor to copy/clone the string because it can do it in following way (directly),

'String test = txtName.Text;'

This is my understanding of .net and java.

I hope I was able to give proper reasoning.

Thanks and Regards

Harsh Baid

Comment: NO NO NO NO. All passing (without `out` and `ref`) in C# is [Call-By-Value(-Of-The-Reference)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). For reference-types this is better described as [Call-By-Object-Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). [Call-By-Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) is unrelated as is a "Copy Constructor". *Immutable* objects [generally] have no need for a "Copy Constructor" -- strings in Java *and* C# are immutable.

Comment: C++ has a very precise definition for a [Copy Constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor), which is used even for even immutable types in C++ -- but that is C++, not C# or Java.

Comment: Garbage collection is a big part of why C++ needs to make copies when C# and Java don't.  In C++, even if an object has immutable **content**, it may need to be cloned, because the copy has different lifetime.  Under a GC system, one can just indefinitely extend the lifetime of the original as long as it is still needed.